# Bootstrap button selector for click event handler

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How to proccess this button `class="btn btn-danger btn-small"` in click event handler function?

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-small" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_kategori" href="<?php echo site_url('ckategori/update_kategori/'.$data->id_kategori);?>"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-small" href="#" id="<?php  echo $data->id_kategori ?>" ><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".btn btn-danger btn-small").click(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var del_id = element.attr("id");
    var info = 'id=' + del_id;
    if (confirm("Yakin akan menghapus data?")) {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>ckategori/del_ajaxKategori",
            data : info,
            success : function() {
            $('#' + del_id).fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

That doesn't work. When I change to `$(".btn").click(function()`, everything works perfectly, but all of my button group calls delete function in my JS.

What I want is when I click `btn btn-danger btn-small` then it calls a delete function.

Comment: Change `$(".btn btn-danger btn-small").click(...` to `$(".btn.btn-danger, .btn.btn-small").click(`

Comment: By the way, `element.attr("id")` can simply be `this.id`.

Comment: @V4KK4R it looks like it should be `$(".btn.btn-danger.btn-small")`, as your first edit was.

Comment: It will work @Regent

Comment: $(".btn-danger") worked

Comment: @V4KK4R after you **edit** it - yes, it will.

Comment: @bluesvega it works for both buttons. But should it work only for second one?

Comment: @bluesvega for only `<a class="btn btn-danger btn-small"` it should be `$(".btn.btn-danger.btn-small")`

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting the `id` of the element via PHP variable

```
<?php  echo $data->id_kategori ?>
```

You could also set the id in the selector via the same php variable?

```
$("#<?php  echo $data->id_kategori ?>").click(function(){
    //DO STUFF
});
```

---

**EDIT:** After re-reading your question (and paying a little more attention to details) - your selector is currently:

```
$(".btn btn-danger btn-small")
```

Which is searching for an element of type `btn-small` in an element `btn-danger` in an element with the class `.btn`

It should be:

```
$(".btn.btn-danger.btn-small")
```

This looks for any elements that have all three classes `.btn`, `.btn-danger` and `.btn-small`

Comment: Yes, this is what is all about: reading question and paying attention to details :) +1 for `$(".btn.btn-danger.btn-small")`